# Where can I learn Cloo or OpenCL.Net?

Tags: opencl, cloo

I'm trying to find a tutorial for learn Cloo or OpenCL.Net, But I didn't find anything decent. Could someone suggest something that I may have missed in the search? Thank you!

Comment: Did you ever find anything decent?